# FullCalendar and ICalendar feeds with custom fields

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar, icalendar

I would like to load an ics file in fullcalendar (vuejs) with custom fields.
I find ics event in vuejs but without custom fields.

I use fullcalendar with fullcalendar/icalendar plugin to parsing ics file :

```js
data() {  
      return {
        selectedEvent: {},
        calendarOptions: {
          themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
          editable: false,
          plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin, bootstrapPlugin, iCalendarPlugin ],
          initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
          headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
          },        
        }
      }, 
      events:{
        url: 'my_ics_url',                             
        format: 'ics',  
      },           
      eventClick: function(info) {                     
        console.log(info.event)
      },
    }
  }
}
```

It work, i find my events into calendar.
But I would like store my custom fields into extendedProps of the event. But actually I only find in extendedProps fields : description, location and organizer

My ics file :

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Evenement_A
UID:ABC-2021-03-26-12:30:00
STATUS:CONFIRMED
DTSTAMP:20210326T123000
DTSTART:20210326T123000
DTEND:20210326T153000
LAST-MODIFIED:19700101T010000
LOCATION:
SITE:
TITLE:event_title
CUSTOM_FIELDS:azerty
END:VEVENT
```

thanks for your help.
Michael

Comment: So... what do you expect to happen to the custom fields data when it goes into fullCalendar? Should it be stored in the extendedProps of the event, perhaps? Please be clear and specific about your requirement, and also provide a full example wherever possible. Also how are you parsing the ics currently into fullCalendar? Are you using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/icalendar? It really wasn't very clear from your description. See the [tour] and [ask] for more guidance, then edit your question. Thanks.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I edit my question. Thanks

Comment: Ok thanks, that's clearer. The built-in fullCalendar ICS parser doesn't have any options for customising its behaviour, you can't specify anything in the setup about that. Therefore you cannot use the standard code to achieve what you want. Your options are 1) look for another ics parser online, 2) write your own parser, 3) take the source code of the fullCalendar ICS functionality and customise it to your requirements, 4) make a feature request to the fullCalendar team to enable what you need. Clearly all of these approaches have advantages and disadvantages, you need to decide what to do